# How can I add the animation "o to number" in my counter? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I would like to add this animation (http://aishek.github.io/jquery-animateNumber/ **EXAMPLE 3**) to my code but seems like it doesn't work.

JSFiddle with code animation: https://jsfiddle.net/252jxsjq/6/
JSFiddle without code animation: https://jsfiddle.net/252jxsjq/5/

Code without animation:

```
var counter = localStorage.getItem('rans') || 0;
var counter = Number(localStorage.getItem('rans')) || 0;
var counter1 = Number(localStorage.getItem('bans')) || 0;

$('.redanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('rans', ++counter);
     $( '.bpercent' ).html( counter1 * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
     $( '.rpercent' ).html( counter * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );

});

var counter1 = localStorage.getItem('bans') || 0;
var counter = Number(localStorage.getItem('rans')) || 0;
var counter1 = Number(localStorage.getItem('bans')) || 0;

$('.blueanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('bans', ++counter1);
     $( '.rpercent' ).text( counter * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
     $( '.bpercent' ).text( counter1 * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
});
```

Example of the Animation to add:

```
<p>Fun level <span id="fun-level" style="color: red;">0 %</span>.</p>

var percent_number_step = $.animateNumber.numberStepFactories.append(' %')
$('#fun-level').animateNumber(
  {
    number: 100,
    color: 'green',
    'font-size': '30px',

    easing: 'easeInQuad',

    numberStep: percent_number_step
  },
  15000
);
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean in your code? Please explain better.

Comment: If I add the code that I want it isn't doing the animation. I posted all the links in my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091729/how-can-i-add-the-animation-0-to-a-number-jquery