# How can I add the animation "0 to a number"? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that when i click a button, the percentage of the div go very fast from 0 to the number of the div.
How can I implement the animation to my code?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/252jxsjq/5/

jQuery:

```
var counter = localStorage.getItem('rans') || 0;
var counter = Number(localStorage.getItem('rans')) || 0;
var counter1 = Number(localStorage.getItem('bans')) || 0;

$('.redanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('rans', ++counter);
     $( '.bpercent' ).html( counter1 * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
     $( '.rpercent' ).html( counter * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
     $('.rpercent').animateNumber({ number: 'rans' });


});

var counter1 = localStorage.getItem('bans') || 0;
var counter = Number(localStorage.getItem('rans')) || 0;
var counter1 = Number(localStorage.getItem('bans')) || 0;

$('.blueanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('bans', ++counter1);
     $( '.rpercent' ).text( counter * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
     $( '.bpercent' ).text( counter1 * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
});
```

Comment: You are senselessly overwriting your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/mVKEBX), looking in to the link provided by **Enkode**.
Here I created a self-calling loop which can go as much as you specify, 100 in this case.

```
$(".clickButton").click(function() {
   var counter = 0;
   var timeDelay = 10; // in millisecond
   var endCount= 100;  // end of loop

   (function loopFunc (counter) {
      setTimeout(function () {
         $("p").html(counter + "%");                

         if (counter++ < endCount) loopFunc(counter);   
      }, timeDelay)
    })(1); 
});
```

The loop will be invoked by clicking `.clickButton`. Then a `setTimeout` function create a pause inside of the loop iteration.

Comment: finally, thenk you very much

Answer (score 0):

You code is not dry and can be condensed and broken in to functions. For your animation you can use a simple while loop with a timer. Here is an example of a while loop with a time. Depending how slow you want your animation you will want to sleep for a shorter / longer time

[How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)